# how to add 6 days to a date variable using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have variable which holds a date value so I would like to add 6 days to the current date variable.  The variable always changes based on user's selection but i always would like to add 6 days to the current date variable.  Here is what i have and i would like to create a variable called `WeekEndDate` and this variable should hold the value of `WeekBeginDate` + 6 days.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    DateTime WeekBeginDate;
    DateTime WeekEndDate;
    if(this.Page.Request["WeekBeginDate"] != null)
    {
        WeekBeginDate = DateTime.Parse(this.Page.Request["WeekBeginDate"].ToString());

        Chart1.Titles[0].Text = WeekBeginDate.ToString();
        WeekEndDate = WeekBeginDate.AddDays(6);


    }

    // load the chart with values

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT DATEPART(DAY,DT)DT, sum (HOURS) as HOURS FROM myTable where  DT >= WeekBeginDate  and DT <=  WeekEndDate  group by DT ";
```

Comment: I would also look into using sql parameters in your sqlStatment. Would not want SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this one:

```
// Initially, we have to parse the weekBeginDate string to create a DateTime object
// and then we add six days to this DateTime object.
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(WeekBeginDate).AddDays(6);

// Then we assign the string representation of the DateTime object we have created before.
Chart1.Titles[0].Text = dt.ToString() ;
```

Comment: But, in the example `WeekBeginDate` is a `string`, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just noticed it. Thank you very much !

Comment: :) +1 for fixed answer.

Comment: It has since been changed back to a `DateTime`. :/

Answer (score 1):

you can add Days this way, but your object should be `DateTime` not `string`:

```
    DateTime WeekBeginDate;

     if(this.Page.Request["WeekBeginDate"] != null)
     {                  
       WeekBeginDate = DateTime.Parse(this.Page.Request["WeekBeginDate"].ToString());

       Chart1.Titles[0].Text = WeekBeginDate.AddDays(6).ToString();

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
WeekBeginDate = DateTime.Parse(WeekBeginDate).AddDays(6).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since `WeekBeginDate` is a string, you first need to look at converting it to a `DateTime` object.

you can use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.

Then you'd just use the [AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do the actual work.

So I would have something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string WeekBeginDate = "";

    if(this.Page.Request["WeekBeginDate"] != null)
    {                  
        WeekBeginDate = (string)this.Page.Request["WeekBeginDate"];
        Chart1.Titles[0].Text = WeekBeginDate ;

        DateTime actualBeginDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(WeekBeginDate, out actualBeginDate))
        {
            DateTime actualEndDate = actualBeginDate.AddDays(6);
            string WeekEndDate = actualEndDate.ToString(); // Pick your favorite string formatting
        }
    }
}
```

I chose `TryParse` instead of `Parse` since the `WeekBeginDate` is coming from the user and you can't really know for sure what format it will be in. So `Parse` may throw an exception.

Comment: Tim, i have updated my initial post but my sql is not working please look at my initial post.  i am not sure what i am doing wrong.  thnx